# boost::posix_time::ptime from const char* "substring"

Tags: c++, boost, unit-conversion

**EDIT**: Actually, while we are at it, I need to do the same thing for a `double` as well - I have something NNNDD in the middle of a `const char*`, where the N's are the whole part and the D's are the decimal (so in 123.45 would appear as a `const char*` to 12345). I know how many whole numbers I'll have, and I know how many decimals, so it's just a matter of getting a fraction out of them.

I have a `const char*` somewhere in the middle of there is a time sequence of the format HHMMSSMMM (hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds). I would like to create a `ptime` out of it (I know where the sequence begins, so I have a `const char*` to its start). Is there a good, efficient way to do this? Right now I am extracting each time unit value, storing them in local variables, and calling the `ptime` constructor with a default `boost::gregorian::date()` and a `time_duration` of `hours(hh) + minutes(mm) + seconds(ss) + milliseconds(mmm)`... but it feels kind of clumsy, roundabout. Shouldn't I be able just pass a time string and not worry about the date?

Answer (score 0):

For the doubles, insert a . and then read it into a double.

```
 const char * pDoubleString = ...;
 const long DoubleStringLength = ...;
 const long DoubleWholeCharCount = ...;

 std::string DoubleAsString = std::string(pDoubleString, DoubleStringLength);
 DoubleAsString.Insert(DoubleWholeCharCount, ".");
 double DoubleValue = std::atof(DoubleAsString.c_str());
```

Comment: Isn't `atof` a relatively expensive operation?

Comment: Sure, but I don't see a better way of converting a `string` to a `double`.